# Attempting to get Access Token for Imgur using XMLHttpsrequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, form-data, imgur

I am attempting to access the access token for my imgur account using XMLHttpsrequest. The imgur doc states that it requires a post method with a body containing refresh_token, client_id, client_secret, and grant_type(which is just "refresh_token"), an example in the  doc shows that you can create a FormData and send that with .send() function for the body, but when I do that in my own code (seen at gen.send(body)) I get the error: throw new TypeError('"string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer'). I don't know what I am doing wrong here, or how to go about fixing it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function generateAT(){
  var gen = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var body = new FormData();
  body.append('refresh_token', refreshToken);
  body.append('client_id', clientID);
  body.append('client_secret', clientSecret);
  body.append('grant_type', "refresh_token");
  
  gen.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (gen.readyState == 4) {
      if(gen.status == 200){
        console.log("works");
      }
      else if(gen.status == 400) {
         console.log('There was an error processing the token.');
      }
      else {
       console.log('something else other than 200 was returned');
      }
    }
    else{
      console.log("not working");
    }
  }
  gen.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token", true);
  gen.send(body);

}
```